# Best UI strategy for adding related entities

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have three related entities:

- a `user` has many `device`
- a `user` has a `userinfo`

I have a process `sell device` that adds `user`, `userinfo` and `device` to the database.
I want to implement this in asp.net pages with a minimum of `postbacks` and an easy to maintain strategy.

One obvious strategy is, first I insert `user`, and then `postback` to `userinfo` page with `id` of the just inserted `user`, after that insert `userinfo`, and then `postback` to `device` page with `id` of `user` and finally insert `device`. This is easy but it involves three `postbacks` that I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of is by using the Master table object as the grid row and then handle the edit capability of the Master row and create EditTemplates for GridView to suit your scenario. Inside edit template, fill up all the related entities and Update/Save it.
For minimum postback, you can wrap this grid inside AJAX (if UpdatePanel does the trick, no need to expose the Update/Save methods as JSON methods)

Hope I am straight to the point.